# Prove that an operator is bounded.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

Let $X = (C([0,1]), \| \cdot \|_{\infty})$. Define an operator $K$ by

$$
(Kf)(x) := \int_{0}^{1} k(x,y) f(y) dy.
$$
Where

$k:[0,1] \times [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous.

My try

$$
\|Kf\|_X = \sup_{x \in [0,1]} \left| \int_{n \to 1} k(x,y) f(y) dy \right| \leq \sup_{x \in [0,1]} \left| \int_{0}^{1} M f(y) dy \right|= \\ = |M| \sup_{x \in [0,1]} | \left| \int_{0}^{1} f(y) dy \right| = |M| \cdot \|f \|_X
$$

Where $M = \sup_{x,y \in [0,1] \times [0,1]} k(x,y)$ which exists since $k$ continuous on compact interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost correct. The idea is fine, but your calculation a flaw. When you estimate an absolute value of an integral 
$$ \def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\abs{\int_0^1 k(x,y)f(y)\, dy} $$
you cannot just make the integrand "larger" to make the integral larger, because of signs. This only works for positive integrands. You have to start with the triangle inequality, 
$$ \abs{\int_0^1 k(x,y)f(y)\, dy} \le \int_0^1 \abs{k(x,y)f(y)}\, dy $$
Then you can go on
$$ \int_0^1 \abs{k(x,y)f(y)}\, dy  \le M \int_0^1 \abs{f(y)}\, dy $$
with $M := \sup_{x,y} \abs{k(x,y)}$ (note the absolute value here, it is needed!).

Comment: And then $\int_{0}^{1} |f(y) dy| \leq 1 \cdot \|f\|_{\infty}$. Thanks!